# TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments on changing timezone

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to change the timezone of UTC to America/Sao Paulo, but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

This is my code:

```
import pytz

local_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
local_dt = candles[0]['time'].replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz)
```

Candle time is:

```
>>> candles[0]['time']
u'2017-08-03T00:03:00.000000Z'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert your `candles[0]['time']` which is a unicode string to `datetime` object.

Here is an example:

```
import datetime, pytz

a = u'2017-08-03T00:03:00.000000Z'
local_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
local_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000Z').replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz)
print local_dt
```

Output:

```
2017-08-02 21:03:00-03:00
```