# Timezone conversion error found when converting the timezone of a large list of timestamps in an excle file with python

Tags: python, excel, timezone, timestamp

I have an excel file named "hello.xlsx". There is a column of timestamps that has a lot of rows (more than 80,000 rows for now). The file basically looks like this:

```
04/19/2018 01:37:33

04/19/2018 01:37:54

04/19/2018 01:37:57

04/19/2018 01:37:59

04/19/2018 01:38:05

04/19/2018 01:38:10

04/19/2018 01:38:38

04/19/2018 01:39:29

04/19/2018 01:39:32

04/19/2018 01:39:44

04/19/2018 01:39:51
```

And so on...

These timestamps are in UTC time, and I need to convert them to US Pacific Time (UTC, -7).

I'm a beginner of python and actually I don't know how to do such conversion. I asked online and got a helpful answer. The code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('hello.xlsx', header=None)

local_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')

df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz).replace(tzinfo=None))

df.to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

However, there was an error after I ran it:

```
TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

I searched online to look for a solution but failed to make it right. I hope someone can help figure it out. New methods are also welcomed. Thanks~ :)

Comment: Where did you get this answer? It's useful for context on why that approach was chosen.

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137360/timezone-conversion-of-a-large-list-of-timestamps-from-an-excel-file-with-python) I guess

Comment: First check what is the data type of the `df[0]` by using `print (df[0].dtype)`. If this gives `datetime64[ns]` then the code above should work. Otherwise you need to do datatype conversion. Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474316/typeerror-replace-takes-no-keyword-arguments-on-changing-timezone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to apply method from the datetime class to str object.
You need to convert the strings read from your Excel file to datetime object before applying the timezone conversion.

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('hello.xlsx', header=None)
local_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
local_fmt = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"

df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, local_fmt))
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz).replace(tzinfo=None))
df.to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: I suspect that `df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, local_fmt))` would be faster with `df[0] = pandas.to_datetime(df[0], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`